# What's the correct way to show a credit or discount on an invoice or order summary?

Tags: credit, accounting, discount

Is there a standardized way to express discounts or credits in an order summary?

Example...

```
Sub total: $20
Discount:  -$10
Total:     $10
```

I've seen discounts expressed as `-$10`, `$-10`, `($10)`, and `+$10`.

Are any of these expressions more "correct" than the other? Is there a common or standardized way to express discounts? Where would these standards be documented?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a universal standard for negative numbers. Accountants *generally* prefer parentheses (possibly since they are more obvious that a negative sign), but consumers may not be as familiar with that convention.

I would say that `+$10` is both redundant (since the absence of a negative sign implies a positive number) and confusing for a discount since it's *implied* that the discount is subtracted. Does the positive mean that the discount is *added* to the total (like a double-negative)?.  But it's not *wrong* per se.

From a sytle standpoint, aligning the decimal point (actual or implied), and sometimes the currency symbol, is preferred visually:

```
Sub total:  $20
Discount:  -$10
Total:      $10
```

Comment: From my (limited) understanding, a balance due is a negative number. So, credits and discounts are additive, not subtractive. Is that correct?